# Trying to change the URL of a product image once I upload it, but there seems to be no way to access the URL

Tags: images

I've uploaded an image to my Wordpress site. I want to use it to set a product image. But, once I drag it into the Media Library the image does not show correctly - rather it looks like a place-holder.  I need to change the URL to point to the correct image in the content folder, but can't change the URL. Advice appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as a product image in core WordPress.

Comment: I believe this is relating to a the WooCommerce plugin, which is not within the scope of this forum.

As a side-note, it would be possible to manually change the URL in the database, under the post's `ID` for the image.